# Need to create a Djano Model, which will provide option to add Custom-model attribute for every django model automatically

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Django rest framework issue-

Suppose we have 4 models right now, 1. User,  2.School, 3.Students, 4.Teachers.

Now all these have some form fields which they need to submit own their own.

Now we need to provide a "add button", Through which if user wants to input some extra data for them from the front-end side, Let's say teacher wants to create a new field from her account from front-end side, she clicks on "add button" after that our "ModelCustomField" field - "heading" will appear in front-end, some input has been entered and she clicks on save button to save it. After saving it, it should be saved in database with table realted to "ModelCustomField" with some additional attributes of table like -

1.user_id

2. Model_related_to

This Model_related_to attribute should save, which model or view the teacher is using right now. but data has been provided to front-end via APIs only.
so Is there any method or technique through which i can implement this theory of mine.
I need to prepare a CRUD functionality for this new custom model.

```
class ModelCustomFields(models.Model): 
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    model_related_to = models.CharField(max_length=500) 
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=500)  - 
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.heading)
```

Comment: So do you want to just link your ModelCustomFields instances with instances of either User, School, Students or Teacher?

Comment: See, we can add foreign key to connect Model-CustomFields from Model1 and use it easily in front-end to create additional-fields(as an attribute of Model-CustomFields). But what if i want to use the Model-CustomFields with every Model1,2,3......n, so that i can get the same functionality with everyone.
Is it possible?

Comment: I think this article could help you https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/